# Assign colors to specific values in a data.frame R - spot the error

Tags: r, colors, dplyr

I have a data.frame called `color` with sample names. I want to assign colors to it according to the ending `.U1` or `.U2`.

```
color
samples  
1  30HB.U2 
2  41ML.U2 
3  22WS.U1 
4  29MK.U1 
5  29MK.U2 
6  40WA.U1 
7  30HB.U1 
8  13BS.U1 
9  50DM.U1 
10 53BD.U1 
11 36ER.U1 
12 05AP.U1 
13 06WT.U1 
14 07RW.U1 
15 07RW.U2 
16 17SK.U1 
17 26FB.U1 
18 28HM.U1 
19 31KE.U1 
20 32FG.U1 
21 34WF.U1 
22 37SD.U1 
23 41ML.U1 
24 45GL.U2 
25 47OT.U1 
26 49RJ.U1 
27 54SL.U1 
28 54SL.U2 
29 69HL.U1 
30 69HL.U2 
[...]
```

```
color <- color %>%
  mutate(col = case_when(
    samples == color$samples[grepl(color$samples,pattern = '.U1') == TRUE] ~ 'red',
    samples == color$samples[grepl(color$samples,pattern = '.U2') == TRUE] ~ 'blue'))
```

Not every color assignment worked.

```
color
samples  col
1  30HB.U2 blue
2  41ML.U2 blue
3  22WS.U1 <NA>
4  29MK.U1 <NA>
14 07RW.U1 <NA>
15 07RW.U2 <NA>
16 17SK.U1 <NA>
24 45GL.U2 <NA>
25 47OT.U1 <NA>
26 49RJ.U1 <NA>
27 54SL.U1 <NA>
28 54SL.U2 <NA>
29 69HL.U1 <NA>
30 69HL.U2 <NA>
31 74SA.U1 <NA>
[...]
50 05AP.U2 <NA>
51 36ER.U2 <NA>
52 40WA.U2 <NA>
53 35AD.U2 <NA>
54 47OT.U2 <NA>
55 28HM.U2 <NA>
56 38AR.U2 <NA>
57 66DG.U2 <NA>
58 35AD.U1 <NA>
59 57MT.U2 blue
60 39DA.U2 blue
61 37SD.U2 blue
62 49RJ.U2 blue
```

Why does it not work? I think it is strange that the first and latter assignments work...
Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mutate(col = case_when(samples == ...))` structure is designed to compare individual values of samples. So as this mutate operation works, it compares each value in `samples` to your logical vector produced by `grepl` over the entire `samples` variable. Unintended results occurred.

Here is a way to do it using your `grepl` expression. Replace `==` with %in% since you want to check if each value of sample is one of the set compared against.

```
color <- color %>%
  mutate(col = case_when(
    samples %in% color$samples[grepl(color$samples,pattern = '.U1') == TRUE] ~ 'red',
    samples %in% color$samples[grepl(color$samples,pattern = '.U2') == TRUE] ~ 'blue'))
```

Here is a simpler way to use `grepl`.

```
color <- color %>%
  mutate(col = case_when(
    grepl(".U1", samples) ~ 'red',
    grepl(".U2", samples) ~ 'blue'))
```

You could also use `str_detect` from `stringr`.

```
library(stringr)
color <- color %>%
  mutate(col = case_when(str_detect(samples, ".U1") ~ 'red',
                         str_detect(samples, ".U1") ~ 'blue'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `substring` and `factor` labels.

```
color <- transform(color, col=factor(substring(db$samples, 6), labels=c("red", "blue")))
color
#    samples  col
# 1  30HB.U2 blue
# 2  41ML.U2 blue
# 3  22WS.U1  red
# 4  29MK.U1  red
# 5  29MK.U2 blue
# 6  40WA.U1  red
# 7  30HB.U1  red
# 8  13BS.U1  red
# 9  50DM.U1  red
# 10 53BD.U1  red
# 11 36ER.U1  red
# 12 05AP.U1  red
# 13 06WT.U1  red
# 14 07RW.U1  red
# 15 07RW.U2 blue
# 16 17SK.U1  red
# 17 26FB.U1  red
# 18 28HM.U1  red
# 19 31KE.U1  red
# 20 32FG.U1  red
# 21 34WF.U1  red
# 22 37SD.U1  red
# 23 41ML.U1  red
# 24 45GL.U2 blue
# 25 47OT.U1  red
# 26 49RJ.U1  red
# 27 54SL.U1  red
# 28 54SL.U2 blue
# 29 69HL.U1  red
# 30 69HL.U2 blue
```

---

*Data:*

```
color <- structure(list(samples = c("30HB.U2", "41ML.U2", "22WS.U1", "29MK.U1", 
"29MK.U2", "40WA.U1", "30HB.U1", "13BS.U1", "50DM.U1", "53BD.U1", 
"36ER.U1", "05AP.U1", "06WT.U1", "07RW.U1", "07RW.U2", "17SK.U1", 
"26FB.U1", "28HM.U1", "31KE.U1", "32FG.U1", "34WF.U1", "37SD.U1", 
"41ML.U1", "45GL.U2", "47OT.U1", "49RJ.U1", "54SL.U1", "54SL.U2", 
"69HL.U1", "69HL.U2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30"))
```